# bash send mail when threshold is exceeded in three successive runs

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that does a pretty decent job on reporting CPU level above 95%.  The issue I am running into is it will report on even "spikes".  This script runs every 10 minutes and checks all of my servers.  Is there a way to only report if the server reports a level above 95% for 3 iterations?  say after the 3rd time it runs, i.e 30 min.

```
12:00 - 1st report - 98%
12:10 - 2nd report - 99%
12:20 - 3rd report - 98%  (now alert the admin)
```

here is the section of the script:

```
for sn in $(cat /tmp/hosts |grep -v "#"); do
  cpuuse=$(ssh -qn -o ConnectTimeout=15 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes $sn "top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep \"Cpu(s)\" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix=\"\$prefix\" '{ split(\$1, vs, \",\"); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub(\"%\", \"\", v); printf \"%s%.1f%%\n\", prefix, 100 - v }' | rev | cut -c 4- | rev")
  if [[ "$cpuuse" -ge 95 ]]; then
    echo "CPU Alert!! $sn CPU is high - $cpuuse%" | mailx -s "CPU Alert on $sn" admin@sample.com
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK There isn't really a `bash` trick. You just need to store a counter somewhere. Something like this could do the trick:

```
for sn in $(cat /tmp/hosts |grep -v "#"); do
    cpuuse=$(ssh -qn -o ConnectTimeout=15 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes $sn "top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep \"Cpu(s)\" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix=\"\$prefix\" '{ split(\$1, vs, \",\"); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub(\"%\", \"\", v); printf \"%s%.1f%%\n\", prefix, 100 - v }' | rev | cut -c 4- | rev")
    counter_file=/tmp/my-counter-file-$sn # separate counter file for each server
    if [[ "$cpuuse" -ge 95 ]]; then
        date >> $counter_file # just add a line to the counter file
        if [[ $(wc -l $counter_file) -ge 3 ]]; then
            echo "CPU Alert!! $sn CPU is high - $cpuuse%" | mailx -s "CPU Alert on $sn" admin@sample.com
            rm $counter_file # message was sent, reset counter
        fi
    else
        rm $counter_file # below limit, reset counter
    fi
done
```

The trick here is to store a counter in a file. The number of lines in the file is your counter value.

Comment: Worked Great! Thanks for the help.  I was actually thinking about something like that, but didn't know if there was a loop or "trick".  Thanks again for the help